# Are there any native speakers of Esperanto in the world?

Tags: native-speakers

Are there in the world any native speakers of Esperanto? If yes, can they communicate with world or do they've to learn another language?

Comment: Yes, there are. Look at this question for numbers: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-many-esperanto-speakers-exist

Comment: If they don't live in a country where everybody speaks Esperanto, they do need to learn another language. Actually, that is not different with what people from Italy, France, and other countries do need to do: I could not write here, if I didn't learn English.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there are natives, but all Esperanto natives have multiple native languages. They usually have parents with different native languages who use Esperanto as language of the house. So the Esperanto natives have a mother tongue, a father tongue, a parents tongue and sometimes even a kindergarden tongue.

Comment: It is of course quite uncommon that the mother tongue, the father tongue, the kindergarden tongue and Esperanto are indeed four different languages. But my children are actually an example of this uncommon situation: They grow up with Russian, German, Luxembourgish and Esperanto.

Comment: @MarcosCramer I'd love to hear more about that! But this isn't really the right medium for it...

Answer (score 2):

I know several native Esperanto speakers personally. As far as I know, they are all at least bilingual. [Wikipedia has an article about this topic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Esperanto_speakers)

Answer (score 2):

[Esperanto like a native](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzDS2WyemBI)
This excellent video also answers quite a few of your questions.
I haven't been learning Esperanto for very long, but I have met quite a few native speakers already. All are - at least - bilingual, because there is no place in the world where you could grow up and only speak Esperanto. 
The ones I have met speak English, French or German as a second tongue, for example.